# How to stop SVG stroke animation on mouseout

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I created an SVG stroke animation using this code:

```
 @keyframes draw {
    30%{stroke-dashoffset:0; fill-opacity: 0;}
    50%{fill-opacity:1;}    
    100%{stroke-dashoffset:0; fill-opacity:1;}  
}

.box-icon:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    svg {
        .path {
            fill-opacity: 1;
            stroke-dashoffset:160;
            stroke-dasharray:160;
            animation: draw 3s linear forwards;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I'm hovering out, the animation restarts again. So it triggers continuously while i need it to start it only on `mouseover` not on `mouseout`.

How to fix that?

Comment: can you make it a working snippet ?

Comment: "It triggers continuously" can you explain that in greater detail? From your code it's not immediately obvious why it would cause the animation to repeat indefinitely.

Comment: Could you use JS? If Yes you, could add a class `onMouseEnter` and connect it to the animation

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Your animation name needs to be changed so that it matches the name of the keyframes for a start. Please provide a proper working snippet.

Comment: Name has been corrected. Yes I can use JS. HTML is basic, i have a div with svg inside.